# `$` is not defined. Uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery. I am facing this problem where the browser is detecting that `$` is not defined. I have seen a lot of solutions to this problem. But turns out none of them are working for me. In my HTML, I'm loading the jquery library from my local directory, before calling my script.

[Directory that contains the jquery library and the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjIg3.png)

[HTML header where I'm loading the scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihZls.png)

[DOM error that the browser shows me every time I load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4U6F.png)

Somehow, I'm not able to find a solution to this error. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: do have jquery.js in your html !?

Comment: Why are you using both the developer _and_ production version of jQuery? One or the other. Also, try loading without `async` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you post complete HTML and JavaScript code rather than images.

Comment: @Andy: I removed the `async` and that solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `async` from your script tags, as this is essentially loading and running those files in parallel, meaning your `script.js` file could be running before your `jquery` files are even loaded.

Also, you don't need to load both the minified and unminified versions of jQuery. Just load the minified version.